# Найти значение в многомерном массиве php

Tags: массивы, php

Есть массив правил:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => 30
            [description] => 30 секунд
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => 45
            [description] => 45 секунд
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [value] => 60
            [description] => 1 минута
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [value] => 120
            [description] => 2 минуты
        )
)
```

и я получаю переменную $rule_value (к примеру  $rule_value = 60)

и нужно проверить есть ли число 60 в данном массиве в ключе value.

Можно ли это реализовать в 1 строку без циклов ?

Копаю в сторону array_map, array_search

Но пока не выходит. Подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так:

```
array_filter($arr,function($a){
  return $a["value"]==60;
});
```

Comment: ну в смысле `count(этого всего)` и сравнить с единицей...

Answer (score 2):

даже и не знаю, попробуйте array_walk, array_walk_recursive что-то из этого но мне кажется проще один раз пройти массив и скажем заменить ключи на значения value

Answer (score 0):

Если есть возможность, сформируйте массив

```
$ar = array(
    [30] => '30 секунд',
    [60] => '1 минута',
    [120] => '2 минуты'
)
//value станет ключом массива.
//Дальше: 
if (array_key_exists($rule_value,$ar)){
   //Обращаемся по ключу к ячейке.
   echo $ar[$rule_value];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$key = array_search($rule_value, array_column($array, 'value'));`